# Option in rewriting some nested if statements

Tags: c#

I have a method which used some nested if statements, so I would like to know if there is a better way to write the same logic.

For example I would like remove avoid the twice

```
_typologyRepository.Update(typology);
_typologyRepository.Save();
```

Could you point me out in the right direction? Thanks

```
  public void Update(Typology typology, string nameOriginalValue)
  {
        if (typology.Name == nameOriginalValue)
        {
            _typologyRepository.Update(typology);
            _typologyRepository.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            if (IsUniqueName(typology.Name))
            {
                _typologyRepository.Update(typology);
                _typologyRepository.Save();
            }
            else
                _validatonDictionary.AddError("Name", errorMessageNameUnique);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want logical operators. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: code review? I add it as a tag?

Comment: @DanielA.White i disagree with you.

Comment: @GibboK - its another stackexchange site. flag it and say to migrate it.

Comment: Why wasn't this posted at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Thanks DanielA for me it is fine, I'm not sure how to move it to the other site, please let me know thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (typology.Name == nameOriginalValue || IsUniqueName(typology.Name))
{
    _typologyRepository.Update(typology);
    _typologyRepository.Save();
}
else
{
    _validatonDictionary.AddError("Name", errorMessageNameUnique);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

RedFilter's answer is how it should be written.  One other note about your code, though:

Usually, when people do cascading if/elses, they keep everything at the same indentation level. RedFilter's answer is better because you don't need cascading if/elses, but if you did need them, most people would write them like this:

```
public void Update(Typology typology, string nameOriginalValue)              
  {                                                                             
      if (typology.Name == nameOriginalValue)                                   
      {                                                                         
          _typologyRepository.Update(typology);                                 
          _typologyRepository.Save();                                           
      }                                                                         
      else if (IsUniqueName(typology.Name))                                     
      {                                                                         
          _typologyRepository.Update(typology);                                 
          _typologyRepository.Save();                                           
      }                                                                         
      else                                                                      
          _validatonDictionary.AddError("Name", errorMessageNameUnique);        
      }                                                                         
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Sam for your answer, I really appreciate your insight!